# IEF reference show parent field as title using Auto Entity Label

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal 8 want to add a field value to IEF reference title. for now I am using Auto Entity Label version 2.x-dev to automatically generate title for my Entities but when it comes to IEF references I wan to get name of parent as title of IEF. as example see below image

[image: I Added Stack overflow as Name to Entity-X]

Then I wan to add a new IEF entity which is using Auto Entity label to generate title automatically

[image: After creating IEF entity]

As you can see it only says 15% complete but I want it to be Stack Overflow 15% Complete

here is tokens that I selected to Auto Entity label to show name in IEF reference.

```
[entity-x:field_name] - [task:field_percent_complete] % Completed
```

This token pattern placed inside Task entity

Note: I Entity-x and Task are two different Entity in system

Comment: I have the same problem to use node field data in the referenced entity field, any suggestion to do that!

Comment: @Nasser What solutions did you tried beside the one I applied in my question?

Comment: I try the custom token module but it has not to option to use the node field in this module https://www.drupal.org/project/token_custom